# Hotel Bookings Bookings Possible

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I have implemented a short algorithm that tells whether all hotel bookings are possible or not. The problem is very similar to [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-platforms-required-railwaybus-station/), but I have tried to implement my own logic.

(Very sorry for such long explaination)

In my algorithm

1. `int` K= Number of rooms available
2. `ArrayList<Integer>` arrive = Arrival time of guest
3. `ArrayList<Integer>` depart = Departure time of guest
4. `int` arriving_guest = Next guest
5. `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` arrange = allocation of rooms

For example

- arrive = [1,3,5]
- depart = [2,6,8] and
- K=1

Now before we begin to iterate the **`ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrange` will be `[[2]]` as initially all rooms are available and `int arriving_guest = 1` as first guest is accommodated it will point to the next guest**

Now for 1st iteration, where the guest's arrival time is 3 and departure time is 6

- Check whether the first room is available
- As the first guest departure time is 2 so his room can be given to 2nd guest so `arrange` will become `[[2,6]]`
- Increment `arriving_guest` to point to next guest

Now for 2nd iteration, where the guest's arrival time is 5 and departure time is 8

- Check whether the first room is available
- As the 2nd guest departure time is 6 so his room cannot be given to 3rd guest so a new room should be allocated for 3rd guest and `arrange` will become `[[2,6],[8]]`
- Increment `arriving_guest` to point to next guest

At the end of the algorithm

Rooms needed = `arrange.size()` = 2

Rooms available = `K` = 1

So it will return `false` value for above

**If I apply my algorithm for the below test case it fails**

- arrive : [ 14, 29, 0, 35, 34, 15, 17, 7, 28, 13, 40, 28, 11, 40 ]
- depart : [ 51, 77, 37, 63, 76, 25, 57, 23, 40, 32, 63, 41, 21, 68 ]
- K : 9

My algorithm is

```
private static boolean bookingsPossible(ArrayList<Integer> arrive, ArrayList<Integer> depart, int K) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int arriving_guest = 1;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrange = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        arrange.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(){{
            add(depart.get(0));
        }});
        for(int i=0;i<depart.size();i++)
        {
            int temp = 0;
            System.out.println("i is "+i);
            while(temp <= i)
            {
                System.out.println("arriving guest "+arriving_guest);
                if(arriving_guest < arrive.size() && arriving_guest < depart.size())
                {
                    System.out.println("i is in if "+i);
                    if(temp <= (arrange.size() -1))
                    {
                    System.out.println("Temp is "+temp);
                    int vacatetime = arrange.get(temp).get(arrange.get(temp).size() - 1);
                    System.out.println("Vacate Time "+vacatetime+" Arrival Time "+arrive.get(arriving_guest));
                    if(vacatetime <= arrive.get(arriving_guest))
                    {
                        arrange.get(temp).add(depart.get(arriving_guest));
                        arriving_guest++;
                        System.out.println("Arrangement made "+arrange.toString());
                        break;
                    }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("Adding room");
                        ArrayList<Integer> p = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                        p.add(depart.get(arriving_guest));
                        arrange.add(p);
                        System.out.println("Arrangement made "+arrange.toString());
                        arriving_guest++; break;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
                temp++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Rooms needed "+arrange.size());
        System.out.println("Final Arrangement made "+arrange.toString());
        return arrange.size() <= K ? true : false;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not going to unpick exactly what's wrong, but I can smell a problem in only keeping track of *departure* dates in `arrange`. Suppose the first entries in `depart` and `arrive` are `5,10`, and the second entries are `2,3`. What will your algorithm do? Is this right? Try pre-sorting the guests by arrival and departure time, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If we generalize the problem it becomes the following: given intervals (a_i, b_i), find a maximum number of segment intersections.

The algorithms as follows:

1. make another array of pairs: (a_i, false) or (b_i, true), where first
   a value indicates the value, and second a boolean flag if it's a start or
   the end of a segment.
2. sort it by the first coordinate, in a case of tie be sure that the end pair goes first.
3. traverse resulting array and keep local room count. If it's a beginning of the segment increase a room count if it's the end- decrease.

Here's an implementation of the algorithm:

```
public class HotelBooking {

    private static class Pair implements Comparable<Pair>{
        final int x;
        final boolean isEnd;

        public Pair(int x, boolean isEnd) {
            this.x = x;
            this.isEnd = isEnd;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Pair o) {
            int cmp = this.x - o.x;
            //in case of tie be sure that end pair comes first
            return cmp == 0 ? isEnd ? -1 : 1 : cmp;
        }
    }

    public boolean hotel(ArrayList<Integer> arrive, ArrayList<Integer> depart, int K) {
        if(arrive.size() == 0 || K == 0) return false; //base case
        else if(arrive.size() == 1 && K > 1) return false; //base case
        else {
            int n = depart.size();
            List<Pair> intervals = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                intervals.add(new Pair(arrive.get(i), false));
                intervals.add(new Pair(depart.get(i), true));
            }
            Collections.sort(intervals);
            int count = 0; //
            int maxRooms = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < intervals.size(); i++) {
                Pair pair = intervals.get(i);
                count += pair.isEnd ? -1 : 1;
                maxRooms = Math.max(maxRooms, count);
            }

            return maxRooms > K ? false : true;
        }
    }
}
```